# Site layout problems when logged in due to admin bar

Tags: css, admin-bar

Is there a way to when logged in have the banner on my page move down so many specified pixels?

This is what it looks like when I'm logged in (as of course the dashboard bar at the top is there and pushes almost everything down (except my banner as it's absolutely positioned).

[image]

And of course this i what it looks like when I'm not logged in.

[image]

I looked on the wordpress codex and found this snippet of code

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
?>
```

So I attempted to use it and tried to tell wordpress if the user is logged in show this banner with this styling, else show the other banner with that styling. However as I'm not a programmer this is all I got.

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
            <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('banner-widget')) : else : ?>  
            <p><img class="banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/BANNER1-averylawoffice.jpg" alt="Banner 1"></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
} else {
    <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
            <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('banner-widget')) : else : ?>  
            <p><img class="h3-banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/BANNER1-averylawoffice.jpg" alt="Banner 1"></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
}
?>
```

But it doesn't work. Of course.

So what can I do to have this banner move down when a user is logged in? Am I on the right track, just missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a CSS question. The admin bar does its best to do this for all sites by giving a top margin to the `<html>` element:

```
margin-top: 28px !important;
```

But if the theme uses certain positioning methods, that rule won't have the desired effect, which is what is happening in your case.

From what you've said, this might fix the issue:

```
body { position:relative; }
```

Also, WordPress adds an .admin-bar class to the `<body>` if you're using `body_class()`, so you could use that as a selector to fix the issue:

```
.admin-bar #my-logo { top: 28px; }
```

Either way, this is a CSS issue and not a PHP one. The actual CSS solution is off-topic for this site, so I'll leave you hear and you can figure it out.